# Finding the zeroes of the function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

I would like to find the zeroes of the following function given that $3-i$ is a zero of $f$:

> $f(x) = 2x^4-7x^3-13x^2+68x-30$

Please explain to me how to do this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Theory of equations might help

Comment: you cannot expect to do much unless it factors; one aspect is the rational root theorem. If that does not finish it, attempt $(2 x^2 + a x + b)(x^2 + cx + d)$ with integers $a,b,c,d$

Comment: Hint: If $a+bi$ is a factor of a *real* polynomial, so is $a-bi$.

Comment: You could brute force this by feeding it into wolfram alpha

Comment: @2012ssohn: if $a +bi$ is a factor of a **real** polynomial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that $3-i$ is a zero, then you know that $3+i$ is also a zero. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem).

This implies that $\left(x^2-6x+10\right)$ is a factor of the original polynomial.
Can you pull it off from here?

Comment: Should I use synthetic division?

Comment: I would just use long division.

Comment: @kunjimamu - I would go with long division.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ be the roots of:

$$f(x) = 2x^4-7x^3-13x^2+68x-30$$

Then by Vieta's formulas:

$$
\begin{cases}
x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=\frac{7}{2} \\
x_1x_2x_3x_4 = -\frac{30}{2}
\end{cases}
$$

Now you know $x_1=3-i$, and its conjugate must be also a root $x_2=3+i$, so the above reduces to:

$$
\begin{cases}
x_3+x_4=\frac{7}{2} - 6 = -\frac{5}{2} \\
x_3x_4 = -\frac{30}{2} / 10 = -\frac{3}{2}
\end{cases}
$$

Then, again by Vieta's formulas, the remaining roots $x_3,x_4$ must be the roots of:

$$x^2 + \frac{5}{2}x-\frac{3}{2} = 0$$